# Is there an issue with using sum formulas on if/query data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I think I'm missing something obvious but I don't know what to Google, I've had quite a look around. I have a list of data some of which is collated with IFS and then moved onto another sheet with QUERY. I want to add it up to put it in a caseload calculator, but I can't get the sum formulas to work, on either version of the data. I've done a quick mock up here, is there something I should be aware of with formulas returning plain text, or wrapping things up in number formats? I can't copy paste as values only because they'll potentially change.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XjQDk0CY3xNXuK0foepI7WdPxLf9cisbloqKKXxiDbY/edit?usp=sharing

Cheers :)
Meg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this formula in the screenshot, the number 1 should not have quotation marks around it. That is of course true of ALL your formulas all over your sheet. Numbers don't take quotes or it forces them to text which is what is messing up your sums.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(1*B2:B))
```

or:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B)
```